# group member distribution algorithm

Tags: c++, distribution

I listen some place and getting some values. 
I want to grouping these values for my ideal group.

For example my ideal group:

```
float group[10] = { -27.f, -28.f, -29.f, -30.f, -31.f, -33.f, -36.f, -40.f, -45.f, -50.f };
```

and some values:

```
float inputs[] = {  -54.6501, -56.6878, -49.5917, -42.457, -38.6332,
                    -33.4834, -40.7184, -37.1994, -33.6179, -33.6831, 
                    -31.3403, -31.0914, -28.8593, -25.398, -26.5037, 
                    -50.1182, -50.4615, -47.0196, -35.7407, -34.6086,
                    -31.556, -31.8881, -29.5504, -27.6697, -26.219, 
                    -26.9407, -26.5384
                };
```

When I distribute nearest value, I found counts:

```
group[0]:6
group[1]:1
group[2]:1
group[3]:0
group[4]:4
group[5]:4
group[6]:2
group[7]:3
group[8]:1
group[9]:5
```

but actually I need to distribute balanced distribution. If group[0] is 6 it can give group[1] and group[2] (it can't give to group[3] different reasons, it can give maximum 2 groups up or down) than:

```
group[0]:3
group[1]:3
group[2]:2
group[3]:0
group[4]:4
group[5]:4
group[6]:2
group[7]:3
group[8]:1
group[9]:5
```

and group[4] can give 2 item to group[3] and group[5] can give 1 item to group[6].

```
group[0]:3
group[1]:3
group[2]:2
group[3]:2
group[4]:2
group[5]:3
group[6]:3
group[7]:3
group[8]:1
group[9]:5
```

Finally group[9] can give 2 items to group[8].

```
group[0]:3
group[1]:3
group[2]:2
group[3]:2
group[4]:2
group[5]:3
group[6]:3
group[7]:3
group[8]:3
group[9]:3
```

I don't know how I can achieve this. I don't have experience about distributing much.

Any suggest? Library?

========================================

I worked with boost uniform distribution. It is not like what I have said but it will work for me I think.

```
float group[10] = { -27.f, -28.f, -29.f, -30.f, -31.f, -33.f, -36.f, -40.f, -45.f, -50.f };
const int GROUPSIZE = 10;

float groupRatio[10];

std::vector<std::vector<float> > grouped;
grouped.resize(10);

boost::math::uniform_distribution<float> groupDist(-50, -27);

for (int i = 0; i < GROUPSIZE; ++i) {
    std::cout << "cdf[" << i << "]: " << cdf(groupDist, group[i]) << std::endl;
    groupRatio[i] = cdf(groupDist, group[i]);
}

float inputsA[] = {  -54.6501, -56.6878, -49.5917, -42.457, -38.6332,
    -33.4834, -40.7184, -37.1994, -33.6179, -33.6831,
    -31.3403, -31.0914, -28.8593, -25.398, -26.5037,
    -50.1182, -50.4615, -47.0196, -35.7407, -34.6086,
    -31.556, -31.8881, -29.5504, -27.6697, -26.219,
    -26.9407, -26.5384
};
const int INPUTSIZE = 27;

std::vector<float> inputs;
std::copy(&inputsA[0], &inputsA[INPUTSIZE], std::back_inserter(inputs));
std::copy(inputs.begin(), inputs.end(), std::ostream_iterator<float>(std::cout, " "));

std::cout << "\ninputs.size(): " << inputs.size() << std::endl;

float max = -150.f;
for (int i = 0; i < inputs.size(); ++i) {
    if (max < inputs[i])
        max = inputs[i];
}
std::cout << "max : " << max << std::endl;
boost::math::uniform_distribution<float> inputDist(-50, max);

float temp;
for (int i = 0; i < inputs.size(); ++i) {
    temp = boost::math::cdf(inputDist, inputs[i]);
    std::cout << "cdf[" << i << "]: " << temp << std::endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < GROUPSIZE-1; ++j) {
        if (groupRatio[j] >= temp && groupRatio[j+1] < temp)
            grouped[j].push_back(inputs[i]);
        else if (j == GROUPSIZE-2 && groupRatio[j+1] >= temp)
            grouped[GROUPSIZE-1].push_back(inputs[i]);
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < grouped.size(); ++i)
    std::cout << "grouped[" << i << "]: " << grouped[i].size() << std::endl;

for (int i = 0; i < grouped.size(); ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < grouped[i].size(); ++j)
        std::cout << "grouped[" << i << "][" << j << "]: " << grouped[i][j] << std::endl;
```

and this is the output:

```
cdf[0]: 1
cdf[1]: 0.956522
cdf[2]: 0.913043
cdf[3]: 0.869565
cdf[4]: 0.826087
cdf[5]: 0.73913
cdf[6]: 0.608696
cdf[7]: 0.434783
cdf[8]: 0.217391
cdf[9]: 0

-54.6501 -56.6878 -49.5917 -42.457 -38.6332 -33.4834 -40.7184 -37.1994 -33.6179 -33.6831 -31.3403 -31.0914 -28.8593 -25.398 -26.5037 -50.1182 -50.4615 -47.0196 -35.7407 -34.6086 -31.556 -31.8881 -29.5504 -27.6697 -26.219 -26.9407 -26.5384 

inputs.size(): 27

max : -25.398

cdf[0]: 0
cdf[1]: 0
cdf[2]: 0.0165962
cdf[3]: 0.306601
cdf[4]: 0.462027
cdf[5]: 0.671352
cdf[6]: 0.37727
cdf[7]: 0.520307
cdf[8]: 0.665885
cdf[9]: 0.663235
cdf[10]: 0.758463
cdf[11]: 0.76858
cdf[12]: 0.859308
cdf[13]: 1
cdf[14]: 0.955056
cdf[15]: 0
cdf[16]: 0
cdf[17]: 0.121145
cdf[18]: 0.579599
cdf[19]: 0.625616
cdf[20]: 0.749695
cdf[21]: 0.736196
cdf[22]: 0.831217
cdf[23]: 0.907662
cdf[24]: 0.966629
cdf[25]: 0.937294
cdf[26]: 0.953646

grouped[0]: 2
grouped[1]: 3
grouped[2]: 1
grouped[3]: 2
grouped[4]: 3
grouped[5]: 5
grouped[6]: 3
grouped[7]: 2
grouped[8]: 2
grouped[9]: 4

grouped[0][0]: -25.398
grouped[0][1]: -26.219
grouped[1][0]: -26.5037
grouped[1][1]: -26.9407
grouped[1][2]: -26.5384
grouped[2][0]: -27.6697
grouped[3][0]: -28.8593
grouped[3][1]: -29.5504
grouped[4][0]: -31.3403
grouped[4][1]: -31.0914
grouped[4][2]: -31.556
grouped[5][0]: -33.4834
grouped[5][1]: -33.6179
grouped[5][2]: -33.6831
grouped[5][3]: -34.6086
grouped[5][4]: -31.8881
grouped[6][0]: -38.6332
grouped[6][1]: -37.1994
grouped[6][2]: -35.7407
grouped[7][0]: -42.457
grouped[7][1]: -40.7184
grouped[8][0]: -49.5917
grouped[8][1]: -47.0196
grouped[9][0]: -54.6501
grouped[9][1]: -56.6878
grouped[9][2]: -50.1182
grouped[9][3]: -50.4615
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, you're calculating the count of how many numbers in `inputs[]` are nearest to the different numbers in `group[]`, and then storing those counts into the positions where these numbers in `group[]` are.  You would like to be able to distribute the count between the different positions, but each position can only distribute two positions away.  Is this correct?

You should check out [Boost/Math/Distributions.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/boost/math/distributions.hpp).  It has quite a few distributions, several of which may be useful in this case.

I think it may be interesting to notice that if you apply the distribution you outlined in the original request enough times, all of the elements in `group[]` will tend towards the average.  In other words, after applying the distribution enough times, you will always end up with an array where all of the elements either equal

`ceil( [total # of numbers in inputs[]] / [# of places in group[]] )`

OR

`floor( [total # of numbers in inputs[]] / [# of places in group[]] )`

For instance, in the array you ended up with in the example in your original request, all of the elements are either 2 or 3.  If you look at your starting arrays, and divide the number of numbers in `inputs[]` by the number of places in `group[]`, you get 2.7.  So basically, this means that if you straight-up average the count of numbers in `inputs[]` between the places in `group[]`, there are 2.7 numbers per spot in `group[]`.  If you applied the distribution you detailed in the original request enough, you would end up with as close to an average as possible (you obviously couldn't have 0.7 of number, which is why some positions have one more number in them than others).

I hope my explanation at least makes a hint of sense.  I would need a clearer definition of the distribution algorithm to try coding it up.  It seems like each number in the distributed `group[]` depends on three to five numbers (itself, and two to four others), so creating a loop which calculates each entry is a tricky problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You well expressed than me. I researched little more and learnt that I need "uniform distribution" concept. Uniform distribution is in boost library. I will check now. Other hand if I write, I need to check item's main home too. If I calculate for 1 group home, I need to check 5 group homes. If I don't check item's main home (flag) first item can be slide more than 2 positions away. Probably it can have more detailed cases.